# Sitefinity, IIS 6 WCF services return home page

Tags: asp.net, wcf, sitefinity

I'm evaluating Telerik's Sitefinity CMS. On my dev box (Win7 x64/IIS7), everything works great.

However, when I deploy the site to our Win2k3/IIS6 server, the backend system doesn't work correctly. According to fiddler, anytime the browser makes an AJAX request to a WCF (.svc) service within the application, the home page is being returned.

Any suggestions?

I've tried:

1. re-registering ASP.net
2. Re-registering WCF with
3. \windows\microsoft.net\framework\v3.*\wcf\servicemodelreg -i
4. Made sure that the .svc extension is allowed
5. Deleted and recreated the site in IIS

Argh. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be related to the IIS6 application pool identity, permissions on the web folder, and having multiple authentication methods checked in site properties. By playing with those things I was able to get it to work.

As a test, I ran the site through the Sitefinity project manager app (using its integrated Cassini server), and everything worked correctly.

Comment: Care to share what settings you ended up with?

Comment: @SteveMallory drop me an email.

Answer (score 1):

You can find installation information and other tips on getting Sitefinity up and running by visiting [the documentation](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/installation-and-administration-guide/installing-sitefinity/configuring-the-iis-to-host-sitefinity-projects.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Unfortunately that was the first place i looked. Their support guys are being very helpful, though. +1 for the only answer so far.